# Sending push notification to mutiple users using fcm,some time token not generated in some device

Tags: android

I had tried some samples,push notification for single user using FCM. It worked fine.Now I am trying to send push notification for multiple user using FCM.Any referral site or code will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

I am sharing my code here.Please have look.

```
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();  
    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
```

Comment: I expected this some will down my question.why you people or doing this.

Comment: I thought like stackoverflow is place to share knowledge

Comment: Check here. Read thoroughly. You will find everything related to FCM here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: But originally what happening is,some one with high reputation will take all credits,without analysing why this question has been asked by some user.

Comment: without clearing the doubt simply they will down vote.

Comment: Dear Sir, I had gone through that link for so many times i got some idea.

Comment: As I mentioned above,i had done for singe user.I have more doubt in that link which you send.

Comment: Have you checked the section "Send Messages to Multiple Devices" ? If yes then please specify the doubt that you are having. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Comment: Apart from that i have another one doubt.App already have a list of user,now I am planing to add push notification.How to send push notification to already registered users of App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use registration_ids key in fcm request:

Push calling format:

```
Link: 
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Headers:
Authorization:key=<server key>
Content-Type: application/json

Body:
 {
       "notification":{
       "title":"Testing 6",
       "body":"PUsh test 6",
       "sound":"default",
       "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",  
       "icon":"fcm_push_icon"     
    },

    "data":{    
       "Type":"ALBUM",    
        },    
   "priority": "high",    
   "content_available": true,    
   "registration_ids": ["token 0","token 1","token 2"]

 }
```

Comment: I had already design the webApp through webApp only i am going to send notification.

Comment: By using the above code,Is it possible to send notification for multiple users.

Comment: yes,  its contains string array

Comment: I had done like this only,but notifcation is not going for multiple device,notification is send for single device alone.

Comment: shall i share my code

Comment: are you using correct authrization key? yes please

Comment: i had just run the apk and shared the app to another device .Device which i shared apk does not receiving the notification

Comment: your issue is with "How to send push notification to mutiple users using fcm
" its done....now your issue with your token...fix your problem first

Comment: I was not sure that i had done it for multiple user.I will look after that token issue and now i will share my code .Please have a look at it.

Comment: i had posted the code of `onTokenRefresh` method.Please have a look at it.Please also share any sample code link for "sending push notification to multiple users".It will be helpfull.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes token is correct, and what about the sever key? are you using from firebase console under setings> cloud message tab.. right? First send push from firebase console notification tab and confirm its working or not...if not then issue on your app side

Comment: This is my Api Key:                                                                                   **Web API Key**  `AIzaSyAcJeFBfdWBrgTCMVLzvi4Pl2Y-8YLd7qE`

Comment: yes,I had send so many messages from the console,every message is delivered to App.But the issue I am facing is when I am sharing the App to another device and send notification.That time only one mobile is getting notifcation.

Comment: @Akila Different devices will have different tokens. So make sure you are adding all the device tokens of the devices to the params while you are sending like Jd Prajapati shown in the code.

Comment: Thank you Done It. I had done it.